# Bounds for 3D optimization with Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, bounds

I can't find the answer. I want to optimize a three dimensional array with a costfunction. The values of the array may not be lower than 1/9999 and not higher than 1.0.

My array is for example this:

```
myarray = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]],
           [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]])
```

I call the optimize function like this:

```
bounds = [(1/9999, 1.0) for i in myarray for j in i for k in j]
opt.minimize(fun=CostFunction, x0=myarray.flatten(), method='Powell', bounds=bounds)
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/OptimalisatiePreset/Main.py", line 74, in <module>
    result = opt.minimize(fun=CostFunction, x0=myarray.flatten(), method='Powell', bounds=bounds)
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\OptimalisatiePreset\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 610, in minimize
    return _minimize_powell(fun, x0, args, callback, bounds, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\OptimalisatiePreset\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2965, in _minimize_powell
    fval, x, direc1 = _linesearch_powell(func, x, direc1,
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\OptimalisatiePreset\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2700, in _linesearch_powell
    bound = _line_for_search(p, xi, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\OptimalisatiePreset\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2643, in _line_for_search
    lower_bound, upper_bound = lower_bound[nonzero], upper_bound[nonzero]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, the following works for me without errors. The answer is not perfect: I think every `x` should be `1.0/9999.0` but it is not. But nevertheless it seems to run and maybe it could be a starting point for you.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

myarray = np.asarray([[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]],
           [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]])

bounds = [(1/9999, 1.0) for i in myarray for j in i for k in j]

def CostFunction(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x)
    
out=minimize(fun=CostFunction, x0=myarray.flatten(), method='Powell', bounds=bounds)
```

Comment: The only thing you have done is change the array to a numpy array? I forgot, but my array is already a numpy array, I edited my question.